# LinkedIn API request fails with "Unpermitted fields present in RESOURCE_KEY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/memberId]"

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying the following request:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:urn:li:person:<person id>)?oauth2_access_token=<token>&projection=(results*(localizedFirstName,vanityName))
```

But I always get a:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Unpermitted fields present in RESOURCE_KEY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/memberId]",
    "status": 403
}
```

If I try to do it using the alternative API:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people?ids=List((id:urn:li:person:<person id>))&oauth2_access_token=<token>&projection=(results*(localizedFirstName,vanityName))
```

An Internal Server Error is returned:

```
{
    "message": "Internal Server Error",
    "status": 500
}
```

I'm using Google Chrome to perform those requests.

I tried using Postman too.

Headers:

```
X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

Got:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 0,
    "message": "Syntax exception in path variables",
    "status": 400
}
```

My app permissions are:

- r_emailaddress
- r_ads
- w_organization_social
- rw_ads
- r_basicprofile
- r_liteprofile
- r_ads_reporting
- r_organization_social
- rw_organization_admin
- w_member_social

I tried other APIs (socialActivity, ugcPosts) and everything looks fine.

I checked my API usages at `https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/<id>/usage` and `people` usage is currently 0%.

The tested user profiles are also public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only use the id (instead of the urn). also the **fields projection is wrong**:

Use:

```
projection=(localizedFirstName,vanityName)
```

Instead of:

```
projection=(results*(localizedFirstName,vanityName))
```

**As example:**

```
curl -H "X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0" \
"https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?oauth2_access_token=<TOKEN>&projection=(id)"
```

Will return

```
{
  "id": <ID>
}
```

and use it as:

```
curl -H "X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0" \
"https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:<ID>)?oauth2_access_token=<TOKEN>&projection=(localizedFirstName,vanityName)"
```

So:

```
{
  "vanityName": "<VANITY-NAME>",
  "localizedFirstName": "<NAME>"
}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

id parameter needs only person_id but you are providing urn.Try this https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:person_id) and don't forgot to include X-RestLi-Protocol-Version:2.0.0 in header while making call.